# Unhandled Runtime Error RangeError: byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to fetch my custom model in my next.js app, the model.json file and the group1-shard1of61 is in the same folder inside the API folder. I getting these errors:

Unhandled Runtime Error RangeError: byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4
GET http://localhost:3000/api/model/group1-shard1of61.bin 404 (Not Found)

My code for loading the model and for creating the api is below. Does anyone know how to solve this?

index.tsx file

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'

const WEIGHTS = '/api/model' //'http://localhost:3000/api/model/model.json' 

 const loadModel = async () => {
    const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(WEIGHTS)
    setModel(model)
  }
```

api/model.ts file

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import model from './model/model.json'

type Data = {
  name: string
}

export default async function modelAPI(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  res.status(200).send(model)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're manually serving `model.json` via api request, but that does not make it auto-magically serve shards as well, so of course it complains with error 404 (not found).

in general, don't serve you model.json manually (don't do `res.send()`), place it in public folder and let next server handle it by itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how do I let next server handle it by itself, do you have a code example?

Comment: simplest is place everything in `/public`, that is served by next.js by default as-is. if you want to customize it, check next.js docs.